# AWS S3 Inaccessible host

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm a beginner with AWS and I'm trying to connect to S3. I have a really simple export but I'm getting error message:

```
{"message":"Inaccessible host: `legal-systems-staging.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com'. This service may not be available in the `eu-central-1' region.","code":"UnknownEndpoint","region":"eu-central-1","hostname":"legal-systems-staging.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com","retryable":true,"originalError":{"message":"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND legal-systems-staging.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com
```

To connect I have this code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

module.exports = function(customENV){ return function(req, res) {
    //get ENV variables
    const aws_accessKeyId = customENV.access_key;
    const aws_secretAccessKey = customENV.secret_access_key;
    const aws_region = customENV.s3_region;
    const aws_bucket = customENV.s3_bucket;

    //configuring the AWS environment
  AWS.config.update({
      region: aws_region,
      accessKeyId: aws_accessKeyId,
      secretAccessKey: aws_secretAccessKey
    });

  new AWS.S3().getObject({ Bucket: aws_bucket, Key: req.body.template }, function(err, data) {
      if (!err) { 
          res.send('good');
      } else {
          res.send(err);
      }
  });
}};
```

Bucket in S3 Management Console has region EU (Frankfurt) and according [this list](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html) it should be right.

Credential are correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As error states, it seems like your bucket is in another region than `eu-central-1`

Comment: log in to your aws console and see in which region your bucket is, and use the same region in your code.

Comment: @Justinas - updated answer

Comment: Where does customENV come from? Is this code running on your local machine? If so you should probably have your credentials set up in ~/.aws rather than doing it in the code like this. If it's running somewhere else (like lambda) then you will need to add a policy to allow that lambda function to access the S3 bucket

Comment: @dbramwell we are using google firebase (don't ask me why) for sending file to AWS S3. Code is running from public website (after firebase deploy). And env values are comming from another system but I tried even hardcoded values and the result is same.

Comment: Can it be that your bucket name is not valid? Can you make S3 Console buckets list printscreen and show `customENV` contents (except credentials)?

Comment: Your bucket and region as shown here appear to be correct, and a problem with credentials would not cause this error.  This suggests you may have a general local problem with DNS resolution.  Can you go to that hostname using an ordinary web browser?  You should see an XML `AccessDenied` error (in your browser, if it works) but anything else suggests a connectivity problem on your machine.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to sound really stupid, but I had that error because, in my `.env` file, I had the values of my bucket and region mixed up.
After switching their values, my code was working again.

Check the access with AWS CLI tools. If you can access via AWS CLI (list, upload, sign URLs, delete, etc), but not via your code, chances are that you are having a similar problem.

Hope this helps someone like me.

Answer (score 1):

I already found where is problem. As I wrote in comments, we are using google firebase for sending file to AWS S3. Problem was that we were using wrong price plan (Spark instead Blaze) and that is why I could not make external call.

Comment: I am having same issue. But I have no paid plan, I have trail account. Would that mean I cannot access S3 using SDK?

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar case, I used .env file to store key, id and region.

This code in **.env** has error:

```
AWS_ID = 'AKIAW6LZAWQJYVSFY6MV'
```

When I removed the single quotes, the error Unknown Endpoint went away.

```
AWS_ID = AKIAW6LZAWQJYVSFY6MV
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when my server was on ipv6 and bucket endpoint(s) were ipv4.

If you use dualstack setting something like this, when initialising the SDK you should be good;

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  useDualstackEndpoint: true,
});
```

I guess you could also just use this setting in `AWS.config.update`.